# How to install aws-wsgi and Flask in AWS Lambda?

Tags: flask, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, aws-cloud9

I pip installed **aws-wsgi** and **flask** using **AWS Cloud9** and then downloaded the zip file.

This file was then uploaded to a Lambda Layer, which was then attached to my Lambda Function. However, I still get the following error:

```
{  
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'awsgi'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "81e04845-856a-4b98-85a4-7de4644e6244",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I also get similar error for flask.
This is weird because I've imported requests, psycopg2-binary and other dependencies the same way. Only these 2 (awsgi & flask) are throwing errors.
Is there a different way to install these dependencies?

**EDIT**

STEPS how I created the layer (working on Windows):

1. Logged into AWS Cloud9
2. installed get-pip.py with the curl command: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
3. `python3 get-pip.py`
4. `python3 -m pip install flask aws-wsgi -t .`
5. cd out of the directory named dependency
6. `zip -r dependencies.zip dependency/`
7. downloaded the zip file
8. uploaded the zip file to Lambda Layers through AWS Lambda Console

Contents of the layer -> **dependencies.zip**

Comment: Show us the contents of you layer and tell how exactly you created it

Comment: @Quassnoi I just editted the question to include the steps & contents. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/packaging-layers.html#packaging-layers-paths):

> When you add a layer to a function, Lambda loads the layer content into the `/opt` directory of that execution environment. For each Lambda runtime, the `PATH` variable already includes specific folder paths within the `/opt` directory. To ensure that your layer content gets picked up by the `PATH` variable, include the content in the following folder paths:
>
> | Runtime | Path |
> | --- | --- |
> | Python | python |
> |  | python/lib/python3.x/site-packages (site directories) |

It means that you should have packaged your dependencies into a folder named `python` (and not `dependency`)

You can do that by doing this:

1. Create a file named `requirements.txt` with the list of your dependencies
2. Run these commands:

   ```
   pip install \
     --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 \
     --target=python \
     --implementation cp \
     --python-version 3.12 \
     --only-binary=:all: \
     --upgrade \
     -r requirements.txt

   zip -r dependencies.zip python/
   ```

You don't have to do that on Cloud9. Any Python distribution (even Windows-based or Mac-based) will do.

The parameters mean:

- `--only-binary=:all:`: don't compile any packages from source on the machine, only use binary distributions.
- `--platform manylinux2014_x86_64`: use the binaries targeting glibc-based distributions for x86_64 according to the [table](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux). Replace `manylinux2014_x86_64` with `manylinux2014_aarch64` if you are going to use your layer with ARM Lambdas.
- `--target=python`: put the dependencies into the subfolder `python` of the current folder (see above why)
- `--implementation cp`: only install dependencies runnable by `CPython`. That's the implementation that runs python code on Lambda runtime.
- `--python-version 3.12`: match the version of the runtime that will be running your lambdas.

Comment: Running into a Signature Expired error as I try to upload the zip file (5MB) to Lambda Layer. Let me get through that and I'll update you.